# finding the last value different than 0 (without VBA)

Tags: excel

I have the following excel table:

```
StartDate  YTDActual
1/1/2013   100
2/1/2013   200
3/1/2013   99
4/1/2013   33
5/1/2013   45
6/1/2013   0
7/1/2013   0
```

Is there a formula that returns, for each StartDate, the associated value in YTDActual, if it is different than 0, otherwise it would return the last YTDActual value different than 0 in the previous rows.

So, basically the formula would produce the following values in the NewValue column:

```
StartDate  NewValue
1/1/2013   100
2/1/2013   200
3/1/2013   99
4/1/2013   33
5/1/2013   45
6/1/2013   45
7/1/2013   45
```

Note that in Jun & Jul the values are 45 because May had the last non-zero YTDActual value 45.

Thanks

Update: Just a clarification, the second table goes onto another sheet, they are not side by side.

Comment: You need to elaborate on the question and give better detail, otherwise we can't answer it correctly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```
Col A      Col B        Col C
StartDate  YTDActual    NewValue
1/1/2013   100          =if(B2<>0,B2,C1)
...
```

Then just drag down the formula in Column C

Comment: Yes, this would work if the NewValue column was side by side with the YTDActual column, unfortunately, Col A & B or on one sheet, then there is another section with dates and the values need to be looked up.

Comment: I don't think it matters if the columns are adjacent or not, if it's column V you just change the formula accordingly.....

Comment: @costa, can you please elaborate / update your question with better explanation - There is no reason why the new formula needs to be on an adjacent cell... there are lots of ways to accomplish what you want, but it GREATLY depends on what your data looks like and, for that, we need quite a bit of elaboration....

Answer (score 1):

If your dates start at A2 and YTD Actual amounts start at B2 try this formula for C2 copied down

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(B$2:B2<>0),B$2:B2)`

that will give you the required results

Comment: This works as well. Could you please post some explanation about the parameters? The expression 1/(B$2:B2 <> 0) seems unusual. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the new data going in a column next to YTDActual? What I am getting at here is does it need to reference the date or could it just be a column C with:

```
=if(B2=0,C1,B2)
```

This would return B2 if not zero or otherwise the cell above it, this could be entered in cell C2 then dragged down to cover the other cells.

If this does not work to have the new data in the columns next to column B above then I think you may struggle to do this without VBA. The problem that you will have is that you cannot create loops, so if a value is zero, you can check for another value, but this may also be zero and so on.

Comment: The answer is NO, the data goes into another section of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this formula for the NewValue column:

```
=IF(INDEX(Availability[YTDActual], MATCH(B2, Availability[StartDate], 0)) <>0, INDEX(Availability[YTDActual], MATCH(B32, Availability[StartDate], 0)), INDEX(Availability[YTDActual],MATCH(0,Availability[YTDActual],0)-1))
```

where Availability is the name of the excel table, YTDActual is the name of the column and B2, B3, ... contain the dates.

Comment: Seems like overkill, wouldn't John or Chris's suggestion work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately they don't work in my case. My situation is even more complicated, I didn't go over all the details, I am not the one developing the spreadsheet.